# GuessGame if/else logic

Tags: javascript

The program generates a random number between 0 and 1500 and stores it in `rndnum` and you have ten guesses, the game tells you uf the number is higher or lower. When you begin playing, at the top, it says "your number is between 0(lownum) and 1500(highnum)" and I want these to change as you make your guesses.

The problem is that when you guess a number <= 1000 and the correct answer is higher, the text above stays the same although the program knows the number is between the parameters.

```
if (inputnum.value > lownum && inputnum.value < rndnum) {
    lownum = inputnum.value
} else if (inputnum.value < highnum && inputnum.value > rndnum) {
    highnum = inputnum.value
}
choosedif.innerHTML = "Your number is between " + lownum + " and  " + highnum;
```

EDIT: full code (https://pastebin.com/VtaFMVS8)

Comment: The best option for you would be to place breakpoints in your code and inspect it line-by-line to see what is happening and where your assumptions are wrong. Learning to use the debugger is a great investment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna guess and say you're only ever performing this action one time when you expect it to be performed multiple times. There's nothing wrong with the code snippet given, however it doesn't tell the full story.

Unfortunately you have to explicitly tell the browser what to do and when to do it. It won't automatically update your HTML unless you tell it to. Javascript's DOM manipulation aspect is largely an event-driven system.

You will need some kind of trigger such as a button being pressed, the value in the input box being changed, or any number of other things that could happen in order to perform a function. In the example below we bind the `changeValue` function to the [onClick event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) of a button. Once that button is clicked and ONLY once that button is clicked will the `changeValue` function run your code snippet, thereby updating the html.

```js
// set up initial numbers
lownum = 0;
highnum = 1000;
rndnum = Math.floor(Math.random()*highnum)
// get elements
inputnum = document.querySelector("#inputnum")
choosedif = document.querySelector("#choosedif")

function changeValue(){
  if (inputnum.value > lownum && inputnum.value < rndnum) {
      lownum = inputnum.value
  } else if (inputnum.value < highnum && inputnum.value > rndnum) {
      highnum = inputnum.value
  }
  inputnum.value = "" // clear input box
  choosedif.innerHTML = "Your number is between " + lownum + " and  " + highnum;
}

changeValue();
```

```html
<input id="inputnum" type="number"/>
<button onclick="changeValue()">Guess</button>
<div id="choosedif"></div>
```

Comment: So I've tried out what you've suggested and I'm still getting the same results. Could you check out the full code to see what could be the issue? I've found that the lower value can't go above 999 and the higher value can't go below 1000. https://pastebin.com/VtaFMVS8

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I tested your full code here: https://jsfiddle.net/Lh7zLsrw/ and everything seems to be working as it should. On the medium setting I was able to get a lower value above 999 and a higher value below 1000. But that seems to be a different question from what you were originally asking. Consider opening up a new question and maybe someone else might be able to help you.